# Get data from a server with Objective-C

Tags: php, objective-c, ios

I'm trying to make a notification system between a PHP server and an iOS device, just like in the Facebook App.

I already know how to make a PHP request via GET or POST and wait for a response. But I would like to receive server's responses without any request, is it possible? Or should I make a request every x seconds?

Comment: response without a request? what's the response to? or about?

Comment: To simplify, I would like to get data from a server without requesting anything.

Comment: that's not getting, that's receiving

Comment: That's true, sorry for my weak english ^^'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look into [Apple Push Notification Service](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html) (APNS). You send a message to the APNS server, and the server sends a notification to the device(s) you specified. This is standard practice for apps like Facebook.

When the device receives a notification, it sends it to the app (if the app is running) or alerts the user (if it's not). The user can choose to start the app, at which point the notification is delivered. The app can then respond by contacting your server to update its information or whatever.